# On a Raspberry Pi, can you open /dev/gpiomem as a file in Java to set GPIO registers?

Tags: java, linux, raspberry-pi, gpio

I'm trying to create a simple and completely stand-alone Java library to access the GPIO pins on the Raspberry Pi. (Existing libraries have dependencies.)

Using SysFs (/sys/class/gpio/*) it's a no-brainer, but it's too slow. Max frequency for toggling a GPIO pin is just above 100 kHz on a RPi 4.

With the diozero library, they can do 24MHz using /dev/gpiomem. I've tried to find a way to make Java talk to this device driver, but with no luck. I think I should be able to open it as a file and write to it, in a similar way to SysFs. But I can't find much that indicate I'm on the right track, certainly not in Java.

Is it possible to open /dev/gpiomem as a file in Java to set the GPIO registers? If it is, does anyone know how to do it, like what the "protocol" looks like? Any links are very much appreciated.

I've been doing Java since it was Oak, and been using Linux for almost as long, but my knowledge kind of ends with the user space.

Comment: You need to use character device. See how `libgpiod` (https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/libs/libgpiod/libgpiod.git/) and it's GoLang counterpart `gpiod` (https://github.com/warthog618/gpiod) are doing.

Comment: 0andriy, thank you for sending me down the rabbit hole. :) However, I still can't find the answer to my question. Is it possible to access /dev/gpiomem directly through Java?

Comment: Okay... Let me try again. The idea is that kernel and user space have established some kind of protocol to communicate without getting racy with what kernel does. For this kind of stuff the Linux kernel provides a character device and set of IOCTLs. One may use direct communication with the kernel via chardev or use a wrapper library. I gave you just examples of the wrapper libraries since you seems need something like this, but in Java. And no,  there is no /dev/gpiomem in the upstream. I.o.w. I even won't google what that crap is and why it exists somewhere :-)

Comment: https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/driver-api/gpio/using-gpio.html

Comment: I looked into `diozero`, they don't probably know how Linux kernel works. For the devices like sensors we have zillions of the **native** drivers that are working in kernel space (thus faster and better), entire IIO subsystem is for that (`libiio` and full infrastructure with it from Analog Devices is open source). GPIO has `libgpiod`, however Java bindings are missed. Somebody can volunteer to provide them I hope.

Comment: Actually they mentioned `libgpiod` there. _By default diozero uses the Linux GPIO Character Device implementation that was added in Linux kernel 4.8._

Comment: See what I recently discovered: https://github.com/sgjava/java-periphery. This is what you can use.

Comment: 0andriy, thanks a lot. As far as I understand, /dev/gpiomem is Raspberry Pi specific and it is meant to replace /sys/class/gpio/* that is deprecated. It is intended as a restricted way of accessing GPIO from user space, instead of using /dev/mem. I would like to use it since it seems to be the fastest way of  accessing the GPIO registers from Java.

Comment: Native drivers are fine, but (if I understand it correctly) they need a JNI interface, and that slows things down too much. I also looked in to the diozero code. They they use /dev/gpiomem for Raspberry Pi and /dev/mem for other platforms. The code is somewhat abstract and I haven't had the time to identify exactly how /dev/gpiomem is used, but the answer to my question is definitely in that code.

Comment: I like the idea of java-periphery, unfortunately it uses JNI wrappers that is too slow for my case. I would probably use it for PWM, SPI, I2C, etc, but I just need as fast as possible  r/w access to the GPIO pins on a RPi4 with no dependencies if possible.

Comment: The correct way in your case is to write a specific kernel driver.

Comment: Since kernel drivers have to be in C, there would be dependencies to non-Java code and I would have to use JNI that is a factor 10 too slow.

Comment: I didn’t get what you meant by this. In-kernel drivers are the fastest possible way to achieve what you want. Everything else is slower or similar by performance. And how JNI even has anything to do with this?

Comment: Is I understand it, I can't write kernel drivers in pure Java, right?

Comment: I dug into the diozero library. The /dev/gpiomem device is opened via some native code and JNI (allthough JNI is not used for the actual r/w). So, I guess the answer to my original question is No. There is no way of doing this in pure java.

Comment: Right, but why is it a problem? You know here is the choice either you want something academical (then suffer with java approach), or working solution (use proper tools). It is up to you, good luck!

Comment: It's not academical. The goal is a dead simple way of accessing the GPIO pins from Java: Download a single jar-file and write two lines of code. My 12 year old son, and everyone else who just started programming should be able to do it. Existing libraries have dependencies, they don't work out of the box, they are often over engineered and use abstract code that beginners don't understand. Why Java? I consider Java the best multipurpose language. Why the need for speed? You will eventually hit the wall if you don't have it.

Comment: Yeah, which is exactly what academical means. Java or Python or Rust — it really doesn’t matter here, you chose Java — it is fine! You won’t get any better speed for **general purpose** setup. Otherwise any dirty hacks like /dev/gpiomem are allowed for a _certain_ cases.

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE: You can use the /dev/mem and /dev/gpiomem registers directly from Java by using Java Natvie Access (JNA). You interface libc's open() and mmap() functions with JNA. You need the open() functions to get a POSIX file descriptor for the memory device, and you need  mmap() to map the physical memory to the virtual memory, where you can access it from Java via the JNA Pointer object.

I implemented this method for /dev/mem. The performance is excellent. On the scope, toggle frequency is 4.2 MHz on a RPi3B+ 32 bit Rasbian. For comparison, that is about 1/4 of the equivalent C code. No doubt an acceptable performance penalty if you want to use Java over of C.

Unlike SysFs, there is no "communication protocol" for /dev/mem and /dev/gpiomem. They represent the physical memory, and you have to consult the chip documentation and read and write the bits in the registers. Like, this is as low level as it gets. You are using Java to write to the bare metal, which is the direct opposite of the Java philosophy. However, I'm very glad you actually can. Next step is controlling a CNC machine, which they say you can't do with Java. :)

ORIGINAL ANSWER: I answer the question myself. I can't find any example of opening /dev/gpiomem as a file purely in Java. Most likely, it can not be done, but I'm still not entirely sure.

The diozero library is the closest you get. It uses native code and JNI just to open the /dev/gpiomem device. The device is mapped to a memory buffer in Java. The buffer is used to read and write to the GPIO registers. Since JNI is not used to read and write to the registers, it is very fast.

Comment: The problem here is that that device is non-standard, and if you are looking for the proper solution that will work on as many hardware platforms as possible, then it needs to use given generic ABI, which is IOCTLs in the Linux kernel. You may call IOCTLs from Java as diozero does.